# Using Swedish characters in Sublime Text 3/LaTeXTools/Skim workflow?

Tags: accents, characters, input-encodings, sublime-text

I’ve recently moved from TexShop to Sublime Text 3/LaTeXTools/Skim for my Latex work. Occasionally I typeset texts in Swedish including “å”, “ä”, “ö” etc characters. 
However, when I open such a previously created .tex file in Sublime Text, these characters appear as “Œ”, “Š” and “š" in the .tex file. They typset correctly though in Skim, whereas entered å/ä/ö in Sublime Text typset incorrect.
Is this a viewer setting in Sublime text that I’ve merely missed?

Below are the packages I use to make this work in TexShop:

```
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the recommended one. It's probable that Sublime Text uses utf8 encoding itself so it would be a good choice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Manuel That gives the following error in every position I have Swedish characters: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined.

Comment: You need to *save* the file with utf8 encoding, apart from using that line of code. I don't know how TeXShop can do that… but may be in Options you find it.

Comment: @Karl A plausible option is: open the file in TeXShop, *copy it*, then open a new one in Sublime Text, *paste it*, and then save the file from Sublime. Then I guess it will be saved as utf8 and will compile fine.

Comment: @Manuel That solved it all.

Answer (score 1):

(Really non-expert answer.)

That's because Sublime Text expects utf8 encoded files, and in TeXShop you have it configured to save them with “applemac”. So, apart from `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you need to *save* the file with utf8 encoding.